# WPF Designer view crashes on loading in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: wpf, sdk, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, design-view

I'm developing a .NET Core 3.0 WPF application on my main computer. This works as it should but when I transfer this project to my laptop (through GitHub) and open it, I get the following error message when I open a XAML view.

```
The .NET Core 3.0 run-time for 'x64' platform configuration is missing or 
damaged. Please download and install .NET Core 3.0 SDK for the 'x64' platform.
(Exit code: 80008096)
```

So after installing the SDK, run-time etc from here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

I'm still stuck with this error. The project builds fine and I can run it, the problem is that the design view is always crashing on the loading of a view.

I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling .NET Core 3.0 SDK and run-time without success, restarting my laptop multiple times but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There was a problem happened if you had the 32 bit version of the sdk installed as well as the 64. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/20/Adventures-in-NET-SDK-Installation-SDKs-not-Showing-Up